# How to handle difference between physical state and logical state?

Tags: uml

I have a state diagram for the behavior of a DVD player, which consists of a drawer to hold the DVD. In the diagram, the closed state and the open state represent the states when the drawer is close and the drawer is open respectively. Suppose that the player is turned off when it is in the open state, with no CD in the drawer and the drawer open, and is then powered on again. Logically, the drawer is in the closed state, but physically the drawer is in open state. Then, if the user presses the load button, the system opens the drawer which has already been in open state, so which has no effect. But the user presses the load button because he sees that the drawer is open and hopes that the drawer will be close if he presses the load button. But he has to press the load button again if he wants to close the drawer. How can I solve the problem like that?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I solve the problem like that?

In practice you would rely on some kind of notification that the DVD player device has been power cycled:

- If the player automatically puts itself into a well-defined state when its power is cycled, you then you could sync the logical state with the (inferred) physical state.
- If the player has sensors to detect the physical state, you could probe them and then sync the logical state to that.
- You could issue an "open" or "close" command, check that the command succeeded, and sync to the physical state that you infer from that.

Comment: Should you?  If you intend the diagram to model that, then yes.  But if you are modeling an idealized DVD player ... or practical player that doesn't cope with random power cycling ... then leave it out.